# casting pointer of base class to unknown subclass possible somehow?

Tags: c++, templates, casting, multiple-inheritance

**Scenario**:

```
BaseClass* pointer = &subClassXObject;  // subClassXObject is object of class subClassX 
                                        // which is derived from BaseClass and 
                                        // Instance<subClassX>. (Instance<subClassX> is 
                                        // for counting instances of type subClassX.)
                                        // Instance<subClassX> is derived from 
                                        // BaseInstance.
```

*&... stands for getting an address, C++ Standard terminology might define object as being the address already, in this case &... is the object itself*

The class of subClassXObject is unknown at this point, it can be any defined subclass of BaseClass.

It is known that it is one of the direct derived subclasses of BaseClass which each also inherit from Instance<subClassX> where subClassX is the name of the direct derived subclass of BaseClass.

Instance<subClassX> inherits from BaseInstance. BaseInstance defines a public pure virtual function which Instance<subClassX> implements, it's name is getDescriptor.

Thus every subClassObject has access to getDescriptor.

```
SubClassX* pointer = &subClassXObject;
pointer->getDescriptor();               // This should work
```

(Or does it not? Now I am riddling: do I have to explicitly implement a base class public method in a subclass in order for someone being able to call it upon the subclass from outside? No..., haven't I?).

I like

```
BaseClass* pointer = &subClassXObject;
pointer->getDescriptor();
```

to work.

*Moving getDescriptor from BaseInstance and Instance<subClassX> to BaseClass and each sub class is possible, however I want users of my BaseClass to only write application logic code, not infrastructure code (even if they only would have to return an Instance<subClassX> methods return value). The idea behind this is to create an object browser into which every sub classes instantiated object is fed and listed without users having to add any non-classpurpose-code.*

Casting pointer to BaseInstance* crashes the application. Thus my question as phrased in the **title**.

Thank you for your caring!

Comment: The title of your question says "...casting pointer of base class to unknown subclass...". The text of your question describes a cast in opposite direction: from subclass to base class. So, in which direction do you want to cast?

Comment: It might be more of a trans-class cast: from BaseClass to BaseInstance as I don't know subClassX. I see it's not quite determinable in code without RTTI (which I don't want to touch), thus I deleted the last paragraph. Maybe some kind of padding of Instance can achieve determinability?

Comment: I don't understand: subClassX is just as much a child of BaseInstance as of BaseClass - even more so as the BaseInstance comes first. If the virtual function table works for BaseClass*, it should work equally for BaseInstance*. It should work if it's declared BaseInstance from the beginning. If it does, why does the app crash after the cast?

Comment: The app works when subClassX is declared BaseInstance* from the beginning. Why does the cast crash?? (If I can exchange the declaration, casting should work?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare BaseClass* pointer as BaseInstance* pointer. Then a cast is not necessary and it works.

You can only use BaseInstance methods then as casting to BaseClass* would crash then. As the methods are used from the object browser this is about infrastructure functions, they make more sense in BaseInstance than in BaseClass, so not being able to use BaseClass methods is fine (BaseClass best contains base application logic methods only).

Answer (score 0):

Just define the function in base class with virtual key word, and the right derived class will be pickup automatically.

```
class Base{
public:
virtual int getDescriptor();
};
```

Comment: when I do this the cast does not crash but it doesn't get applied: Base::getDescriptor() is called instead of subClassX::getDescriptor (which gets its getDescriptor virtually from Instance). Moving everything to BaseClass and subClassX would work but as written I don't want to do this.